# Php endless loop over and over?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$offset = 0;
$find = "is";
$find_length = strlen($find);
$string = "This is a string, and it is an example.";

while($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)){

echo $find. " Found at ". $string_position ."<br>";
$offset = string_position + find_length;

}


?>
```

keeping getting "is Found at 2" over and over . i am expecting " is found at 2", then  5, then 25

Comment: make sure you have `$`s before all the variables.

Comment: actually: make sure that you have enabled notices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$offset = string_position + find_length;
```

Use variables instead of constants

```
$offset = $string_position + $find_length;
```

If the needle is found at the beginning of the string, `strpos()` returns `0`, which means, that the loop will never start.

```
while(($string_position = strpos($string, $find, $offset)) !== false) {
  // code
}
```

Additional change your error settings in your development environment

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Now you will get this as notice

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant string_position - assumed 'string_position' in php > shell code on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0

Notice: Use of undefined constant string_position - assumed 'string_position' in php shell > code on line 4

Call Stack:
    1.2172     636208   1. {main}() php shell code:0

PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant find_length - assumed 'find_length' in php shell code on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0

Notice: Use of undefined constant find_length - assumed 'find_length' in php shell code on line 4

Call Stack:
    1.2172     636208   1. {main}() php shell code:0
```

Answer (score 1):

`$` sign is missing at:

```
$offset = string_position + find_length;
```

Also, a small bug: if the string is found at position 0, the loop will end.

Answer (score 1):

missing some $, try :

```
$offset = $string_position + $find_length;
```